# Conditional Choice field in django model

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible or good practice to set choice field relative to another choice field as in example below :

```
CHOICES = (
(1,'a'),
(2,'b)
)
choice1 = (()())
choice2 = (()())

class ABC(models.Model):
    choice = models.IntegerField(choices = CHOICES)
    nested_choice = models.IntegerField(choices = [if 1 then choice1 elif 2 then choice2])
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it from Django forms. You need to use JavaScript for achieving this.

Comment: i need to make an API endpoint . what should i do to save both fields ?? should i just put the second choice field null and do something in serializer ?

Comment: I think you are confused about the validation in the django. Add validation before you save to the database